# List of numbers into dimensional Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following problem:
I have a .txt file form my professor, which contains different numbers.
Every number is in another line. There is nothing else in this file.
Those numbers represent coordinates, eg. first line = first x coord., second line = first y coord. and so on. We may not use LINQ.

So my question is: How can I transfer these numbers into an 2d-array like the following?

```
coordArray[0,0] = line1 of textfile (x1)
coordArray[0,1] = line2 (y1)
coordArray[1,0] = line3 (x2)
```

I already tried the following without success:

```
        string path = @"C:\coords.txt";
        int lines = (File.ReadAllLines(path).Count())/2;

        List<double> xy = new List<double>();
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string coord;
            while ((coord = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                xy.Add(double.Parse(coord));
            }
        }

        double[,] coordArray = new double[lines, 2];
        for(int i = 0; i<lines; i+=2)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<lines; j++)
            {
                coordArray[j, 0] = xy[i];
                coordArray[j, 1] = xy[i + 1];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't use `File.ReadAllLInes` just to get the number of lines when you can calculate it after you populate your `xy` list.  That way you don't read the entire file twice.

Comment: "I already tried the following without success" - what was unsuccessful about it? Does your code not compile? Does it crash when you run it? Does it make Alexa order things you don't want? We aren't here to do your homework, we are here to help you with specific problems.

Comment: @florian It's good to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask or even this one http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions otherwise it's harder to answer any question let alone be worthy resource for anybody reading this in future

Comment: @Chris Sorry, I know you have something better to do. Didn't want to bother you with easy stuff, but I just couldn't think about the solution.

Comment: @florian: The thing is broadly speaking your code has the right shape so you're thinking along the right lines, you just have one or more bugs in your code. Finding those bugs is very hard when you don't tell us what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try change last two `for` cycles in your example into:

```
for(int i = 0; i<lines; i+=2)
{
    coordArray[i/2, 0] = xy[i];
    coordArray[i/2, 1] = xy[i + 1];
}
```

Your original solution with two `for` cycles iterates twice over all lines while you want go through them just once but process two lines in every iteration.

note: when there is even number of lines then program will throw an exception

Comment: Given that lines is actually half the number of lines in the file will this not get only half the coordinates?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Replaced it according to juharr's solution.

Comment: you've right, I overlooked fact it's divided by 2 during initalization of lines